# Binding column definition width property in Xamarin.forms grid layout

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, data-binding

I am trying to set the width property of column definition in grid layout to a bindable property it gives me this statement `System.NotSupportedException: Don't know about Xamarin.Forms.GridLength` all i want to do is bind column definition width to be related to device dimensions by binding with property named "ww" in my page popuppage1 instead binding it with the property named "w" in my popupentity class so idk what I am doing wrong in here ,thx in advance
my code is as follows:

**popuppage1.xaml.cs**

```
namespace DOTFORMS3.Views{   
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class popuppage1 : Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages.PopupPage
{
    public int width = (int)DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Width;
    public int height = (int)DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Height;
    public GridLength ww { get; set; }
    public GridLength hh { get; set; }       
    public popuppage1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var dbconn = new SQLiteConnection(Model.HelperMethods.dbPath);
        dbconn.CreateTable<popupentity>();
        mytb = dbconn.Table<popupentity>().ToList();
        MCET = new ObservableCollection<popupentity>(mytb);
        InitializeComponent();
        this.BindingContext = this;
        dbconn.Close();
       
        ww = (width-20) / 2;
        hh = (width - 20) / 2;
        Padding = 20;
    }
    public static List<popupentity> mytb { get; set; } = new List<popupentity>();
    public ObservableCollection<popupentity> MCET { get; set; }

    private void MTZ_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
    {            
        var product = e.Item as popupentity;
        var xx = BindingContext as popuppage1;
    }  
}
```

and here is my xaml code
**popuppage1.xaml**

```
<pages:PopupPage     
xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
xmlns:animations="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Animations;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
x:Class="DOTFORMS3.Views.popuppage1">      
    <ScrollView >
    <ListView HasUnevenRows="True" ItemsSource="{Binding MCET }" SelectionMode="None"  >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell >
                    <Frame>
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Label Text="{Binding DIS1}" IsVisible="{Binding isDIS1}"></Label>
                              <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions >
                                        <ColumnDefinition  Width="{Binding w}">/ColumnDefinition>
                                        <ColumnDefinition  Width="{Binding w}" ></ColumnDefinition>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="{Binding w}" ></RowDefinition>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="{Binding w}"></RowDefinition>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Image Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Source="{Binding image1}"></Image>
                                <Image Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Source="{Binding image2}"></Image>
                                <Image Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Source="{Binding image3}"></Image>
                                <Image Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Source="{Binding image4}"></Image>
                             </Grid>                                                                
                        </StackLayout>
                    </Frame>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</ScrollView></pages:PopupPage>
```

and here is my popupentity class

```
public class popupentity : TableEntity
{
    public int width = (int)DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Width;
    public int height = (int)DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Height;
   public popupentity()
    {
        w = (width - 20) / 2;
        h = (width - 20) / 2;
    }

    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement, Column("_id44")]
    public GridLength w { get; set; }
    public GridLength h { get; set; }
   
}
```

Comment: have you tried to debug? eliminating portion of code by commenting out? to know or narrow from where this error is coming. I can't reproduce could you try to simplify your code by leaving only the minimal relevant code ?

Comment: Is it possible to get where the error occurs by adding a breakpoint？

Comment: the error comes from this section `[PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement, Column("_id44")]
    public GridLength w { get; set; }
    public GridLength h { get; set; }`  i guess i cannot store data of type GridLength in my SQLite database, so i want to bind my grid layout column definition and row definition to the property called `ww` in `popuppage1.xaml.cs` even though the grid is a child of a list view whose item source is `MCET`, so i guess what i am trying to do is a binding  within another binding

Comment: https://www.telerik.com/blogs/using-xaml-xamarin-forms-part-2-accessing-static-data

Comment: why dont you put star as a width property to the 2 columns and it will take screen dimension .<ColumnDefinition  Width="*" ></ColumnDefinition>

Comment: i would like to bind the width property of the grid to a property that is different from the item source of the list view so basically the question is can the child have a binding property different from the father, in my case the grid is the child and the list view is the father where the father binding to an item source called `MCET` and the child i would like it to get bonded to a property called `ww`

Comment: Try to use the int type directly.